# Catching and handling exception in flutter future http request method called from different class

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, try-catch

I have class with static Future method that makes http request. This method is encapsulated within try catch. Most of the exception is handled here.

```
class AuthenticationServices {
  static late User users;

  static Future<int> loginWithUernameAPI(
      String username, String password) async {
    try {
      Map loginData = {'username': username, 'password': password};
      final responseLoginUser = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(Constants.userLogin),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: loginData,
      );
      if (responseLoginUser.statusCode == 200) {
        return responseLoginUser.statusCode;
      }  else {
        return responseLoginUser.statusCode;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.toString(), name: 'SocketException');
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.toString(), name: 'TimeoutException');
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.toString(), name: 'HttpException');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.toString(), name: 'Exception');
    } catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.toString(), name: 'Exception');
    }
  }
}
```

This method is called from another route. Like below

```
AuthenticationServices.loginWithUernameAPI(
                              _usernameController.text,
                              _passwordController.text)
                          .then((value) {
                        responseStatusCode = value;
                        if (responseStatusCode == 200) {
                          developer.log("autheticated");
                          context.loaderOverlay.hide();
                          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<MenuActivity>(
                              context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return const MenuActivity();
                            },
                          ), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                        } else if (responseStatusCode == 404) {
                          context.loaderOverlay.hide();
                          developer.log("not autheticated");
                        } else {
                          developer.log(responseStatusCode.toString());
                          context.loaderOverlay.hide();
                          developer.log("not autheticated");
                        }
                      }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10),
                              onTimeout: () {
                        context.loaderOverlay.hide();
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                            content: Text(Constants.connectionTimedOut),
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
```

When I produce error, app crashes, throws an exception which is not the behavior I want.I am trying here to provide suitable error according to the exception generated.

**Note:** I have added breakpoint to debug. The app is routed to try catch only after throwing exception which is not handled by the defined try catch.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want to show snackbar on errors. So you can rethrow the exceptions and catch them in your method call itself. The other option is to create a model class `ExceptionModel` where you can pass the message and then return it from the method and then show snackbar.